# Increase count according to partition in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a new column which will have value starting from 1 and will increase based on partition.

My input `dataframe` looks like:

```
--------------+------------------+------------+
registerNumber|share_class_number|no_of_shares|
--------------+------------------+------------+
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000100|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000150|
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000100|
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000000|
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000050|
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000000|
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000150|
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000|
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000|
      YYYYYYYY|                 2|   000000100|
      YYYYYYYY|                 2|   000000000|
```

My output `dataframe` looks as below:

```
--------------+------------------+------------+------------
registerNumber|share_class_number|no_of_shares|Group_number
--------------+------------------+------------+------------
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050| 1
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 1
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 1
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000100| 3
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 3
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 3
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000150| 4
      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000| 4
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000100| 1
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000000| 1
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000050| 2
      XXXXXXXX|                 2|   000000000| 2
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000150| 1
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000| 1
      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000| 1
      YYYYYYYY|                 2|   000000100| 2
      YYYYYYYY|                 2|   000000000| 2
```

`RegisterNumber` and `share_class_number` are primary `keys` where each `RegisterNumber` can have multiple `share_class_numbers`.

When we have a non-zero value in `no_of_shares`, a `Group_number` should be assigned staring from 1 and it must increase by 1 when next non-zero value comes in `no_of_shares`.

The `Group_number` should again reset(start with 1 again) when different `share_class_number` or `RegisterNumber` arrives.

I am looking for a solution to this problem. Any leads would be helpful
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Muskan, welcome to stackoverflow! If the first value (for a partition) is 000000000, what should be the group value?

Comment: without any ordering column, the expected output cannot be guaranted.

Comment: Muskan, please check if there can be a column that could retain the original order.

Comment: Ronak Jain There won't be a scenario where first value of a partition will be 000000000.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
df\
.withColumn("no", F.when(F.col("no_of_shares") != "000000000", 1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn("Group_number", F.sum(F.col("no")).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("registerNumber"), F.col("share_class_number")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))\
.show()
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Input:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------+
|registerNumber|share_class_number|no_of_shares|
+--------------+------------------+------------+
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000100|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000150|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000100|
+--------------+------------------+------------+
```

Output (I retained the intermediate columns for understanding, you can drop them):

```
+--------------+------------------+------------+---+------------+
|registerNumber|share_class_number|no_of_shares| no|Group_number|
+--------------+------------------+------------+---+------------+
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|  1|           1|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           1|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           1|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000050|  1|           2|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           2|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           2|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           2|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           2|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000100|  1|           3|
|      XXXXXXXX|                 1|   000000000|  0|           3|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000150|  1|           1|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000000|  0|           1|
|      YYYYYYYY|                 1|   000000100|  1|           2|
```

Comment: THe logic is good but without an `orderBy` clause in the window, you cannot guarantee the result as the outcome is non-deterministic.

Comment: @Steven Yeah, I asked the OP for an ordering column due to the same (earlier had used different logic which needed a concrete order) but it worked with this so deleted my comment.

Comment: There's another condition which needs to be fulfilled here. The value of column `Group_number` depends on one more `field/indicator` whose value comes as `Y/N`. When `indicator` is `Y` - the count for `Group_number` increases, as soon as indicator is `N` the count must reset again.

Comment: @MuskanMakhija Which column? Can you update your question accordingly?

Comment: ```registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|Group_number|
--------------|---------------|------------------|------------|------------|
XXXXXXXX      |Y              |1                 |000000001   |1           |
XXXXXXXX      |Y              |1                 |000000000   |1           |
XXXXXXXX      |N              |1                 |000000001   |0           |
XXXXXXXX      |Y              |1                 |000000001   |1           |
XXXXXXXX      |Y              |1                 |000000000   |1           |```

Comment: @RonakJain I am not able to post the data clearly. But if you can format the above data. You would be able to understand I guess.

Comment: @MuskanMakhija You can edit the original answer instead of commenting. I'll check about this new column. Also, before that please take a look at Steven's comment.